# How does Websphere implement DRS?

Tags: websphere

I've read about Websphere's Data Replication Services (DRS), which is the backbone of its clustering services.

What I don't know is what is its implementation - how does it transfer data and reconcile possible differences? Is it based on RMI or JMS or something altogether different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAManager. Read more [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/crun_ha_hamanager.html) and [here](http://www.devwebsphere.com/devwebsphere/2005/09/hamanager_desig.html).

Comment: Looks like IBM removed those pages. Google HAManager and you'll find some info.